# When WhatsApp takes backup on Google Drive?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I am aware that Local back up is done by WhatsApp daily at **2 AM**, from the official [FAQ](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921) of WhatsApp. Below is the relevant quote:

> Local backups will run automatically every day at 2am and save your
>   database in a file on the phone itself.

But if I opted for Google Drive back up and selected the Frequency as **Daily**, then there is no clear time mentioned in the official WhatsApp/Google Drive info pages.

Same question can be extended for other Back up frequencies. For example  if **Monthly**, then which **date of Month** back up will be taken or if frequency is **Weekly**, then which **day of the week** back up will be taken to Google Drive.

**My Question:** Is there a way to know **when/at what time** WhatsApp takes Back up to Google Drive(and not a local backup, its already known, at 2AM Daily) for each of daily/weekly/monthly option?

Comment: Try it out and check the timestamps? BTW: That "2am" seems to be for a specific time zone which not necessarily matches the TZ the user/device is in ;)

Comment: Answer  seems logical too. Do you feel differently? Asking since i didn't see any response on the answer